# Why doesn't Node detect my recently created file

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, semaphore

I have a Node.js script that subscribes to a notification service and runs a bunch of things when push notification is received. However the service sometimes sends multiple notifications for the same event, so to avoid duplicate work I made a basic semaphore to block other tasks.

The problem is that Node still continues with execution despite the fact ***I see the file created on disk***. I've tried a few different solutions but I think the problem comes from my lack of experience with the JS execution model, there's something I don't know about how it works that prevents my solution from working. **How do I fix this?**

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');

// notification handler callback
function handleRequest(data)
{
    try{
      var semaphore = fse.readJsonSync(__dirname + '/' + objectId);
      console.log('task already running, stopping');
      return;
    }catch(err){
      // semaphore doesn't exist, ok to proceed
      console.log('starting new task');
      fse.writeJson(__dirname + '/' + objectId, {objectId: objectId})
          .then(stepOne).catch(rejectPromise) 
          .then(resp => stepTwo(resp, data)).catch(rejectPromise)
          .then(resp => stepThree(resp, extra)).catch(rejectPromise)
          .then(resp => stepFour(resp, argument)).catch(rejectPromise)
          .then(sleep(20000))                        
          .then(resp => releaseLock(objectId))
          .catch(resp => rejectionHandler(resp);
    }
}

function releaseLock(objectId)
{
    return fse.remove(__dirname + '/' + objectId);
}
```

**Other things I've tried**

- Create file in a separate function that returns promise, same outcome
- Use Sync method to write file, but then I'm unable to chain promises
- Wait synchronously after file creation, no effect

Comment: So you are saying even if there is no error in `try` block the code enters the `catch` block?

Comment: @priyanshgupta yes that's another way of looking at it. The only way to get into the catch block is if a file doesn't exist, but I see it created on the filesystem

Comment: `fse.writeJson` is async, so in theory `handleRequest` could be called another time before any write was done by `fse.writeJson`. You should create an exclusive lock for `objectId` and only if the lock was created successfully, then you should do the task.

Comment: So you need to stop anyone from calling `handle request` if you see any file in the fs with the same objectId?

Comment: @t.niese so the fact I've chained it via promise to other functions changes nothing? The idea is that stepOne shouldn't run before the file is created

Comment: @priyanshgupta yes precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create an external file to maintain locks, you can do something like this, this will also give you the performance boost ( less I/O opts).

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');

// notification handler callback

class NamedLocks {
    constructor() {
        this._pid = {};
    }

    acquire(pid) {
        if (this._pid[pid]) {
            // process is locked
            // handle it
            return Promise.reject();
        }

        this._pid[pid] = true;
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    release(pid) {
        delete this._pid[pid];
    }
}

const userLocks = new NamedLocks();


function handleRequest(data) {
    userLocks.acquire(objectId)
        .then(() => {
            // semaphore doesn't exist, ok to proceed
            console.log('starting new task');
            fse.writeJson(__dirname + '/' + objectId, { objectId: objectId })
                .then(stepOne).catch(rejectPromise)
                .then(resp => stepTwo(resp, data)).catch(rejectPromise)
                .then(resp => stepThree(resp, extra)).catch(rejectPromise)
                .then(resp => stepFour(resp, argument)).catch(rejectPromise)
                .then(sleep(20000))
                .then(resp => userLocks.release(objectId))
                .catch(resp => rejectionHandler(resp))
        }).catch(() => {
            // handle lock exist condition here
        });
};
```

In this, you basically ask for a lock and if the lock exists, handle that in catch handler else do your thing and release the lock

Comment: Yes ! brilliant, thank you so much. I just tested this it works perfectly

Comment: I would prefer to use `release(pid) { delete this._pid[pid]; }` otherwise you have a small memory leak.

Comment: As a note: This will work fine if you don't run your application as cluster with multible worker processes. So if you plan to utilize more then on cpu core in future then you might want to add a check in `NamedLocks` that would throw an execption in that case that reminds you that you need to implement a file based or any other global lock. @blackbird